# Singleton using enum

Tags: java, singleton, enum

Is this the correct implementation of a singleton using enum?

```
public class Item3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Singleton s=Singleton.Single.INSTANCE.getInstance();
    Singleton s2=Singleton.Single.INSTANCE.getInstance();
    System.out.printf("%b",s==s2);
}
}


class Singleton {
    enum Single{
    INSTANCE;
    Singleton s=new Singleton();
    public Singleton getInstance(){
        if(s==null)
            return new Singleton();
        else return s;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, it is simpler to code than that:

```
enum Singleton
{
    INSTANCE;

    // instance vars, constructor
    private final Connection connection;

    Singleton()
    {
        // Initialize the connection
        connection = DB.getConnection();
    }

    // Static getter
    public static Singleton getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Then you use can use `final Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance()`. Note however that since this is an enum you can always access this via `Singleton.INSTANCE`.

And NEVER do that:

```
public Singleton getInstance(){
    if(s==null)
        return new Singleton();
    else return s;
}
```

this is not thread safe! What is more, the `new Singleton()` value is never assigned to `s`... (thanks @DaveJarvis for noticing this!)

Comment: thanks. if I need to obtain a Database connection using singleton in this fashion then I would write `enum Singleton{
 INSTANCE;
 Connection c=DB.getConnection(); 
}` and use `Connection con = Singleton.INSTANCE.c` in client code? Please correct me if my understanding is not correct

Comment: See my edit. While you _could_ make the connection available as you say, it is something I would not recommend personally.

Comment: @fge I know that this will help avoiding multiple objects creation from reflection and deserialization  and cloning but will it also avoid creating multiple instances from threading?

Comment: What if you're initialization throws an exception?

Comment: @Mario then `try { ... } catch (Whatever e) { throw new ExceptionInInitializererror(e) }`

Comment: How to pass `connectionString` to Enum

Answer (score 7):

```
public enum Singleton{
   INSTANCE;
}
```

This is enough; you can directly use `Singleton.INSTANCE` to get the instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your response and other samples in [Singleton_pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

```
public enum Singleton {
        INSTANCE;
        public void execute (String arg) {
                //... perform operation here ...
        }
}
```