# Enum Singleton implementation in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, enum, singleton

I just wanted to implement the enum singleton in java. Here is my implementation where I have tried to create a singleton `DataSource` instance:

```
public enum EasySingleton {
    INSTANCE;

    private DataSource dataSource;

    private EasySingleton() {
        this.dataSource = MYDB.getDataSource();

    }

    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

and get this `DataSource` instance just like this:

```
DataSource dataSource = EasySingleton.INSTANCE.getDataSource();
```

I just wanted to confirm whether my implementation is correct or not. If it is wrong then please tell me how to implement the enum singleton to create a singleton `DataSource` instance.

Comment: I think this covers it pretty well already: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27296/singleton-using-enum?rq=1

Comment: Please include your `MYDB` class as well — at least the `MYDB.getDataSource()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good use for a enum singleton. What you have there is a wrapper for `MYDB.getDataSource()`. You could handle that with a `static synchronized` method.

```
public class DataSourceAdapter {
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    public static synchronized DataSource getDataSource(){
        if(dataSource == null){
            dataSource = MYDB.getDataSource();
        }
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference between yours and @Rahul s solution is the execution time. I would prefer your solution:if anything goes wrong the stacktrace will include the reason of the instanciation. And application startup will be faster.